# How to write a text to file with GWT on Client-side?

Tags: java, file, gwt, writer

Is there any way to implement write/read file with gwt on client-side?
I tried with java.io.File, java.io.Writer ... I couldn't succeed.

thx in advance!

**Update: Please see my own [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24463510/416996) for a solution**

Comment: If you mean you want your server-side app to write to the client-side disk, the answer is "You can't". This would be a major security issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently, I've stumbled upon a library called [client-io](http://www.ahome-it.com/client-io/).

> A simple library that brings the Flash File API to regular web apps
>   through GWT. ClientIO will help you offload some of the file
>   generation functionalities to the client, saving resources and heavy
>   computation to the server. Working Demo - http://ahome-it.github.io/ahome-client-io/

Comment: Download button won't work and there seems to be no code other than Hello World

Answer (score 9):

No, you can't write to files on the client-side.  GWT only binds a subset of the Java language.  Any file IO would need to happen on the server side through RPCs or some kind of web service.

Answer (score 6):

It's possible with HTML5 in some modern browsers. Try [lib-gwt-file](http://code.google.com/p/lib-gwt-file/). This library can read files from client computer and even supports DND. To see it in action follow [this link](http://www.vectomatic.org/gwt/lib-gwt-file-test/lib-gwt-file-test.html).
More information on HTML5 FileAPI you can find in the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/).

To download a file from browser memory to the client computer you can use [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). Example is [here](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/). But this feature is supported by Google Chrome only. Also take a look at the following helpful function. It runs download without reloading current page:

```
public static native void setWindowHref(String url)/*-{
    $wnd.location.href = url;
}-*/;
```

Another semi-crossbrowser way is [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify). It's based on flash. Check this [example](http://pixelgraphics.us/downloadify/test.html).

Answer (score 0):

In GWT the classes in the client folder are only compiled into javascript hence it is not possible to use

> java.io

since GWT does not provide compilation of the package

> java.io

Hence you have to write text file through RPC only.